# Installing Meteor.js without Chocolatey

Tags: windows, meteor

As the title reads, I'm looking for a way to install [Meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/install) without [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) package manager. Any way I can do that? I should also mention that I'm running Windows.

Comment: Can I ask why? Meteor switched to `choco` because it has less bugs than the old installer and makes debugging a failed install much easier

Comment: Security reasons, as `choco` requires disabling the firewall.

Comment: It's really bad they require chocolatey installation, chocolatey comes with administrator requirements, security issues and no proper way to completely/correctly uninstall at least on windows, makes it simpler to just use a linux VM, which is really not a simple thing to have to use on a daily basis. I really hope they get rid of this piece of "brown" software in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There appears to be an installer available at https://install.meteor.com/windows. I was able to see this in the [installation script](https://install.meteor.com/):

```
if [ "$UNAME" ">" "MINGW" -a "$UNAME" "<" "MINGX" ] ; then
    echo "To install Meteor on Windows, download the installer from:"
    echo "https://install.meteor.com/windows"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Apparently that is a binary that basically just tells you "Meteor is now installed on your computer," while not having actually done anything (as of Aug 2020, anyhow).

Answer (score 1):

There is a new native NPM-based method to install Meteor without Chocolatey. See the guide: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/npm-packages/meteor-installer/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Chocolatey requires the installation of .NET binaries. I think that there are a lot of developers who love to avoid .NET for a variety of reasons, and thus would avoid Chocolatey, too.

If you are using Windows 10, installing the Linux subsystem is a great solution. Then you can install meteor from a linux prompt with:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

A set of instructions for installing the linux subsystem on Win 10 are [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10).

Answer (score 0):

I updated maka-cli ([www.maka-cli.com](http://www.maka-cli.com)) to include an installer for windows 10 (also works on Linux and Mac):

`npm install -g maka-cli`
`maka install meteor`